# Open Python Script with pythonaddins.GPToolDialog from Addin Wizard

Tags: arcpy, import, python-script-tool, python-addin, error-000576

I created a addin from python addin wizard with many menus and buttons. For one of these buttons I want to open a Python (.py) script from my Toolbox. I tried many ways but no one works. I want this because this script open the parameter dialog box with some parameters to input. I really need to open the windows to put the parameters.

```
class ConfereChave(object):
    """Implementation for ConfereChave.button (Button)"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.enabled = True
        self.checked = False
    def onClick(self):
        pythonaddins.MessageBox('Text', 'Confere Chave', 0)
        relPath = os.path.dirname(r'F:')
        TBX = relPath + r"\Agro\Agro.tbx"
        pythonaddins.GPToolDialog(r'F:\Agro\Agro.tbx', 'ConfereChave')
```

I get this error:

```
Executing: ConfereChave F:\AgroBD.gdb\IBGE\Brasil_Municipios Alfabetico 
COD_IBGE teste1 Float
Start Time: Fri Jul 21 00:31:52 2017
ERROR 000576: Script associated with this tool does not exist.
Failed to execute (ConfereChave).
Failed at Fri Jul 21 00:31:53 2017 (Elapsed Time: 0,69 seconds)
```

I already put the relative path but do not work too.

Code updated but do not work, the same error remains.Remember CampoConfere is a python script (py)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that this is because installing a Python AddIn copies folders to locations well known to ArcMap/ArcPy without updating all paths within the scripts copied.

I do something similar to what you are wanting to do in one of my applications and I have code like that below in my `test_addin.py` which looks like it is designed to find the tool at its new location:

```
import os
relPath = os.path.dirname(__file__)
PythonTBX = relPath + r"\test.pyt"
pythonaddins.GPToolDialog(PythonTBX, 'TestTool')
```

Note that I am using a Python Toolbox (`*.pyt`) tool whereas you are using a Standard Toolbox (`*.tbx`) with a Python script tool but I think the same coding pattern should work.

Comment: Yes, you can use it with a script tool, too

Comment: PolyGeo, I updated the code, but not work...I got the same error when I run the script. The path is updated. I also updated the code in this question.

Comment: Andreas, it's not working with a python script...even putting the relative path